# xtend code generation calling entities from an xtext grammar

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I am working on a code generator for my grammar that I have created:

```
Domainmodel:
    (elements+=AbstractElement)*;

PackageDeclaration:
    'package' name=QualifiedName '{'
        (elements+=AbstractElement)*
    '}';

AbstractElement:
    PackageDeclaration | Type | Import;

QualifiedName:
    ID ('-' ID)*;

QualifiedDate:
    INT('-' INT)*
;

Import:
    'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard;

QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
    QualifiedName '.*'?;

Type:
     (data+= DataType)* man+=Entity  ;


DataType:
    'tag' name=Tag;

Tag:
    Hobbies='hobbies' | Work= 'work' |Fun='fun'
;

Entity:
    name=Category '{'
       feature+=Feature*
    '}'
    ;
Feature:
    component+=Man(',' component+=Opt)*
;    
enum Category:
    Blog='blog' | Article='articles'
;

Man:
    name='title' '=' type=QualifiedName
 ;

 Opt:
    Tags|Date
 ;

 Tags:
    name='tags' '=' '['type= Tag(','tag+=Tag)*']' 
    |
    name='tags' '=' '[' ']' 
    ;

Date:
    name='date' '=' type=QualifiedDate
    ;
```

I want my output of my code generator to look like this:

```
---
layout: post
title: "My Trip"
categories: blog
excerpt:
tags: [fun,hobbies]
image:
feature:
date: 2016-06-01T14:19:19-04:00
modified:
---
```

All I can get right is the static text, I can't seem to call: Category , title , tags , date
I've been trying for so long now but I can't seem to get anywhere, I keep getting strange errors which i don't understand

One of my attempts for just seeing what I can generate is:

```
class MyDslGenerator implements IGenerator2 {

def compile(Entity e) 
{

    '''

    ---
    layout: post
    title: "My Trip"
    categories:«e.name»
    excerpt:
    tags: [fun,hobbies]
    image:
    feature:
    date: 2016-06-01T14:19:19-04:00
    modified:
    ---
    '''
}
override doGenerate(Resource input, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
    for (e : input.allContents.toIterable.filter(Entity)) {
        fsa.generateFile(
            e.generateName,
            e.compile)
    }
}
```

when I run the generator I don't get anything replaced by <>. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've submitted a suggested edit to apply the code formatting. Blocks of code are formatted by being indented by 4 spaces. There's a toolbar button which will do this for selected text when you're writing the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/**
 * generated by Xtext 2.10.0
 */
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.tests;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.xtend2.lib.StringConcatenation;
import org.eclipse.xtext.junit4.InjectWith;
import org.eclipse.xtext.junit4.XtextRunner;
import org.eclipse.xtext.junit4.util.ParseHelper;
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Exceptions;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Domainmodel;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.tests.MyDslInjectorProvider;

@RunWith(XtextRunner.class)
@InjectWith(MyDslInjectorProvider.class)
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class MyDslParsingTest {
  @Inject
  private ParseHelper<Domainmodel> parseHelper;

  @Test
  public void loadModel() {
    try {
      StringConcatenation _builder = new StringConcatenation();
      _builder.append("Hello Xtext!");
      _builder.newLine();
      final Domainmodel result = this.parseHelper.parse(_builder);
      Assert.assertNotNull(result);
    } catch (Throwable _e) {
      throw Exceptions.sneakyThrow(_e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the parsing test not the generator. - how do you run the generator?

Comment: by using a gradle task is the build.gradle file

Comment: sry i dont get that. without having your complete code it is impossible to follow what you are actually doing, what is the expected result and what is the actual result

Comment: im trying to upload the projeect using gethub but i cant seem to get it right

Comment: just take the time you need i will have a look tomorrow. or you simply have a look at mine https://github.com/cdietrich/xtext-forum-support-example/tree/generator-problem

Comment: yes I managed it https://github.com/Eyad123/myRepo/tree/master/git/org.xtext.finalagile.mydsl

Comment: that's my complete project

Comment: can you try `tasks.withType(org.xtext.gradle.tasks.XtextGenerate) {
    options.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
}`

Comment: oh thank you ever so much. it worked at long lat. you're a life saver

Answer (score 1):

is this a question on how to walk the AST. your grammar and thus the inferred metamodel is quite "bad" to walk so you may have to do something like

```
title: «(e.feature.head.component.head as Man).type»
```

so i recommend you to restructure your grammar/AST to fit the stuff you need.

you can set the encoding for the xtend/xtext plugin like this

```
tasks.withType(org.xtext.gradle.tasks.XtextGenerate) {
    options.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
}
```

does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunatily I'm new to all this and only one example was explained, so mainly I'm working on trial and error. If you can recommend recources that I can use that would be helpul. I've tried the xtext and xtend examples but I still don't understand how to solve it.

Comment: This is my output when I run the code generator: ---
layout: post
title: �(e.feature.head.component.head as Man).type�
categories:�e.name�
excerpt:
tags: [fun,hobbies]
image:
feature:
date: 2016-06-01T14:19:19-04:00
modified:
---

Comment: make sure you get the encoding right. what is the encoding of your xtend file / and or project (rightklick on project)

Comment: this is the ecoding i found in the mwe2 file : windows-1252

Comment: i mean the one for the project: rightclick, properties, resource

Comment: You should use utf 8 or ISO 8851 1 I think

Comment: unfortunately I'm still having the same issue even after changing the encoding type

Comment: anything else other than GitHub! Sorry I haven't used it

Comment: just anything that lets me check your complete code

Comment: my complete code is what ive posted, is there anything specifice?

Comment: no i mean the genrator file, it it is encoding specific it is important i get the eclipse project with its prefs in the .settings folder and the complete generator file as is

Comment: i have two 'prefs' files in my project setting folder, one is ' buildship ' and one is 'resourses'

Comment: 'buildship' code : connection.arguments=
connection.gradle.distribution=GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION(WRAPPER)
connection.java.home=null
connection.jvm.arguments=
connection.project.dir=
derived.resources=.gradle,build
eclipse.preferences.version=1
project.path=\:

Comment: resource code: eclipse.preferences.version=1
encoding/<project>=windows-1252

Comment: i thought you would have switched to utf-8?

Comment: and how does the generated java file for the xtend file look like. where should be something like _builder.append("categories:");
    Category _name = e.getName();
    _builder.append(_name, "");
    _builder.newLineIfNotEmpty();

Comment: i just booted windows and cp1252 is fine. thus please post the complete genenerated java file for the generator

Comment: is there a way that i can share the whole project so u can c the code that you r talking about? also, i did shange the encoding in the project to ISO-8859-1 but i dont know why in the setting file it comes up as windows-1252!!

Comment: this is what i meant before by uploading to https://github.com/ or https://gitlab.com or zipping it and share it via cloud storage etc - and it might be related to gradle that it is set to cp1252